# How to check a value type?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I check the type of a value on runtime?

I'd like to find out where I'm creating doubles.

Comment: That's impossible with C. Unlike with C++ where you could use typeid or overload resolution. Or do you look for compiler specific solutions?

Comment: Since you've tagged your question with "iphone," I would guess you mean Objective-C and not "normal" C.  If so, please retag your question.

Comment: Are you referring to an NSValue?

Comment: I'm referring to C types. I also tagged it as cocoa-touch to specify the environment, in case that would make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Objective-C classes, then the `[myObject isKindOfClass: [InterestingClass class]]` test is available. If you're using primitive types (which your question, quoting the "double" type, suggests), then you can't. However unless you're doing some very funky stuff, the compiler can tell you when primitive types do or don't match up, and when it doesn't will perform implicit promotion to the desired type.

It would be beneficial to know a little more about what the specific problem is that you're trying to solve, because it may be that the solution doesn't involve detecting the creation of doubles at all :-).

Comment: Hey Graham. I read that doubles in the iphone should be avoided. I'm using floats with quite a lot of digits in some places, so I just wanted to check if those were actually doubles.

Answer (score 0):

With very few exceptions, you never need to check type at runtime.  Typed variables can only hold their assigned types, and type promotion is determined at compile time.

Comment: I think people have marked you down because you've brushed over the situation where the type is lost due to passing/copying in a void pointer (where type is lost completely). In this case, original type information is unrecoverable.

Comment: Yes, it is unrecoverable, and thus not a situation covered by any possible answer to this question anyways.